# How to find item within List<T>?

Tags: c#, list

Need to search a List to see if it contains a matching object. Cant use Linq so need to go old school.

I need to do a duplicate check before allowing the new object to be added to the TranslatorScriptList.

```
TranslatorScript ts = new TranslatorScript(blah1, blah2, blah3);
if (TranslatorScriptList.Contains(ts))
{
    // Matches, do stuff
}
```

They are of the same type but it came to be that the .Contains is not matching because "ts" is not actually in the list so when it compares the memory addresses dont match.

How can I simply check if the object already exists in the list or not?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a `Set<T>` instead to prevent duplicates?

Comment: `foreach` and test for whatever "equality" you are looking for? Other option would be to override `==`.

Comment: So override the Equals (and HashCode) method. Or provide a custom IEqualityComparer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This will let you supply a predicate that returns the item you are looking for.

```
TranslatorScript ts = new TranslatorScript(blah1, blah2, blah3);
var match = TranslatorScriptList.Find(x => x.Property == ts.Property);
if (match != null)
{
    // Matches, do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Exists` instead of `Contains` which allows you to pass in a `Predicate<T>`. Note that this is not `Linq`. `Exists` is implemented directly in `List<T>`.

```
TranslatorScript ts = new TranslatorScript(blah1, blah2, blah3);
if (TranslatorScriptList.Exists(item => item.Blah1 == ts.Blah1))
{
    // Matches, do stuff
}
```

**EDIT**: Re-reading your question it looks like you're wanting to add only if it doesn't exist so we can simply change the condition:

```
TranslatorScript ts = new TranslatorScript(blah1, blah2, blah3);
if (!TranslatorScriptList.Exists(item => item.Blah1 == ts.Blah1))
{
    TranslatorScriptList.Add(ts);
}
```

Comment: I knew there was a more direct way for this.  I couldn't remember the name and didn't see it on MSDN.  This is better than my answer if you don't need a reference to item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can code `TranslatorScript` so it implements `IEquatable<TranslatorScript>` and override `GetHashCode()` in a way that makes one instance matches with another.

See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx